# How to calculate google maps max and min Lat And Long

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I work on web application using Google Maps JavaScript API.

And i have this problem:

When the user open the app it generates map with some custom markers.
The markers are stored in Database ( SQL ) with latitude and longitude.
I have the user location and radius lets say 10km.

I need to get from database only the markers that are 10km ( radius ) from the user.

So in my where clause i need specific values for lang. and long. borders.

Is there some Google API function or other method to calculate that.

The example:

I have this SQL struct:
table Markers

```
CODE                int         
LOCATION_LATITUDE   float           
LOCATION_LONGITUDE  float
```

Now in JS i generate map with `center = user location`.

And now i want to add only markers from table Markers that are in 10km radius of the map center( user location ) 
In table Markers i have markers from all around the globe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps api locate corner coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534643/google-maps-api-locate-corner-coordinates)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Bounding Box coordinates for my google map window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652867/how-to-get-bounding-box-coordinates-for-my-google-map-window)

Comment: @geocodezip I saw these questions but it have nothing to do with my ... ? map.getBounds(); -> Returns the south-west latitude/longitude and the north-east latitude/longitude of the current viewport: this is very nice but i don't need this. I need a way to calculate from given point and radius the 4 values of Lang and Long to put in my where clause so i can select only these that are in the range ...

Comment: Please, provide more details with real example and database table structure as well.

Comment: You want a radius around a point or a rectangular bounds?  Those two queries will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution. -> Haversine formula

Let's say that point with coordinates ( 37, -122 ) is the center of the map.
So, the where statement will be

`SELECT 
code
FROM MARKERS 
WHERE
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) < 10`

Where 6371 is the Earth’s radius in km ( 3959  in miles ), and 10 is radius of the search area.